# How do I change the font color for keywords "for, if, return" in Visual Studio 2019 for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I migrated from VS2017 to VS2019. One thing that I noticed in dark theme is that the keywords "for, if, return" are white in color. Before, they used to be blue.

I went to Environment -> Fonts and Colors. No matter what I change for the C++ fonts, these ones are always white. What display item should I be clicking to change them back to blue?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I tried Tools->Options->Environment-Fonts & Colors and selected the "C++ Keyword - Control" and it sets the colour for those keywords to what I select. Are you sure you are changing the settings for "Text Editor" in the drop-down at the top-centre of the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color for these keywords by going to

**`Tools`** `->` **`Options..`** `->` **`Environment`** `->` **`Fonts and Colors`** `->` **`C++ Keyword - Control`**

and selecting the color of your choice.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, then. Mine has blue selected for C++ Keyword - Control, but the mentioned keywords appear as white.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. I changed the font to a different random color, and then back to blue. It updated the color after that.

Comment: Using version 16.6.0 it may have changed as there is no options C++, but the same can be found under Keyword - Control.